# Regarding Formula Field in SalesForce

Tags: formula-field

**In User Object, I have Created a one Custom Field Called Profile Calculation as a Formula Field and Return Type as Percentage

In user Object,if i fill firstName,LastName,Email,Title the Profile Calculated Custom Field Shows 40%,if i fill Country the profile Calculated Custom Field Shows 70%,Phone and Mobile it shows 100%,in User Object

How to Write Formula for this Using Formula Field**

Comment: Please Guide Me for the Anaswer

Comment: Share formula code?

Comment: ((%lastname+%FirstName+%Email+%Title)40+(%country)30+(%phone+%Mobile)30)/100

Comment: It is Not Working ,Please Guide Me For the Answer

Comment: @itzmukeshy please Guide Me for Answer

Comment: As you said **it shows 40% 70% 100%** then what is the problem?

Comment: it is Not Working ,Syntax Error,Please Guide Me

Comment: I want Formula Code for the Profile Calculated Field

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Syntax Error, I Want Answer from You itzmukeshy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a formula field of `Percent` type:

```
MIN(1,
 IF( OR(  ISNULL(FirstName),  ISNULL(LastName),  ISNULL(Email), ISNULL(Title) ), 0, 0.4) +
 IF( ISNULL(Country), 0, 0.3) +
 IF( OR(  ISNULL(Phone),  ISNULL(Mobile) ), 0, 0.3)
)
```

I've added `MIN` just in case if someone later will adjust the formula that max summary will go over a 100% to top at 100%.
Also, if any field from each `IF` formula will be blank, 0% will be assigned for the group. If you want to assign 10% for each populated field from the first group, split it into a separate pieces like `IF( ISNULL(FirstName), 0, 0.1)`

Comment: @itzmukeshy hi if any one of the fields missing in first four(first name,Last Name,Email,Title),Remanining all fields are filled also,it should return 0% percent only,first four fields are filled,second expression  are missing and third expressions are also filled it should return only 40%,1 and 2 expressions are filled ,it should return 70%,3 expressions are filled it should return 100%

Comment: @Elavarasan I have already shared; and my implementation works for every field value as in first expression there are 4 fields if any one of them is filled then you will get the % for that field not 0; let say if `FirstName` is only field filled by user then you will get profile status `10%` not `0%`; What you say want to modify this as want to implement that same as per my answer;

Comment: @Elavarasan **Mandatory 1 expression are filled,2 and 3 are also filled it should return 0** what do mean by this?

Comment: @Elavarasan You want to give full % if all the fields are filled right?

Comment: @Elavarasan `(FirstName, LastName, Email,Title) 40% or 0%` then `(Country) 30% or 0%` and `(Phone, Mobile) 30% or 0%` right?

Comment: @Elavarasan try oleksiy's answer first;

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38535/discussion-on-answer-by-oleksiy-regarding-formula-field-in-salesforce).

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

To do so **you need to create more than one formula fields**:

1. Create a formula field for country like this `IF(ISBLANK( MailingCountry ), 0, 30)` and set return type as `Number`;
2. Create a formula field for first name like this `IF(ISBLANK( FirstName ), 0, 10)` and set return type as `Number`;
3. Create a formula field for last name like this `IF(ISBLANK( LastName ), 0, 10)` and set return type as `Number`;
4. Create a formula field for email like this `IF(ISBLANK( Email ), 0, 10)` and set return type as `Number`;
5. Create a formula field for title like this `IF(ISBLANK( Title ), 0, 10)` and set return type as `Number`;
6. Create a formula field for country like this `IF(ISBLANK( Phone ), (IF(ISBLANK( MobilePhone ), 0, 30)), (IF(ISBLANK( MobilePhone ), 15, 30)))` and set return type as `Number`;

   **Hide all the above 6 formula fields from all UI for all users. As we don't want's to show these to anyone these are just for calculation only;**
7. Now create final formula field which will be visible to users and write formual for this something likes this `(Country_status__c + First_Name_status__c + Last_Name_status__c + Email_status__c + Title_status__c + Contact_Number_Status__c ) / 100`;

That's it;

Comment: Try this tested with first two fields; let me know if you face any error;

Comment: Steps numbered now have a try;

Comment: For this you have to write if condition as i wrote for the last 2;

Comment: Please Guide for the Third Step

Comment: Okay do let's do it in simple way for the all four fields create 4 formula same as coutry the first one with returning value of 0 OR 10; Got it;

Comment: Try updated answer;